# Using Resource controller in Laravel 5.6

Tags: php, laravel

I am Using Resource controller in Laravel 5.6. I am following [this](https://www.5balloons.info/tutorial-simple-crud-operations-in-laravel-5-5/) tutorial. I found here `Resource controller uses the Route model binding, This means that you dont need to fetch the specified task by the id. Laravel will do it for you. $task variable which is passed into the show() method is passed to the view via compact method.`

In my code I am using below code in `Controller`.

```
 /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  \App\sura  $sura
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function show(Sura $sura)
    {
        return $sura;
    }
```

Here I am getting the Whole `Sura` object not the `id`.

Why I am getting the whole object not the id ? Where is the issue ?

Comment: can you share the resource you create

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/routing#route-model-binding

Comment: @ali, Here is the route `Route::apiResource('suras', 'SuraController');
`. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/routing#route-model-binding
When dependency inject model

```
public function show(Sura $sura)
{
    return $sura; // it is instance of Sura 
}
```

For get id use this

```
public function show($suraId)
{
    dd($suraId);// return integer number
}
```

Comment: @abuabu are you try it?

Comment: Thanks @Davit. I am reading your answer. But I would like to know about what is saying in the `Tutorial`.